# Number theoretic problems complete for $\mathsf{RL}$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, randomized-algorithms, nt.number-theory, logspace

Are there number theoretic problems (such as those related to $\mathsf{gcd}$) that are in $\mathsf{RL}$?

Can these also be $\mathsf{RL}$-complete problems (is there any $\mathsf{RL}$-complete problem at all)?

Comment: (Well, if $\: \mathsf{RL} \in \{\hspace{-0.02 in}\mathsf{L},\hspace{-0.03 in}\mathsf{NL}\hspace{-0.02 in}\} \:$ then there are $\mathsf{RL}$-complete problems.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Ofcourse $\mathsf{RL}=\mathsf{L}$ implies $\mathsf{RL}$-complete problems exist. However converse is not true.